Accessing Custon Networks
Team,
How can one access a custom network on safe?
My safe address was used by a project on ETH with distributed rewards being sent to that address - however, the rewards were distributed on their new L1 using my Safe address.
Whilst adding custom networks on MetaMask is fine, can you advise how to recover these funds via safe?
Network details below:
Network Name: BasedAI
RPC: https://mainnet.basedaibridge.com/rpc//
Chain ID: 32323
Symbol: BASED
Block Explorer: https://explorer.getbased.ai/#/explorer
Thanks

Since Safe contracts are not deployed on BasedAI, you would first need to deploy them before being able to recover your funds.
Then, to recover the funds, you will have to follow the step described in this guide and this video.
Please let me know if you have any further questions. If not, could you kindly mark this question as solved?
Thank you in advance!
Best, Louis
